# Jave getparameter with # in it

Tags: java, tomcat, escaping

Say I have the URL:
http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=#9QLU9CY8

And then code:

`String search = request.getParameter("search");`

Then search is blank...

I need a way to get around this. The url is visited directly. Is there something I can do in Tomcat's config to make this work?

I tried replacing "#" with "%23" with a `search.replace` but that also didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the '#' character is not part of the parameter but is a fragment identifier. So your parameter is actually empty

see this link to get more info about url params structure

[https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5]

Or

[https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A]

For the formal definition

Comment: unless you can change the format of the search url with one compatible with url params, you can only get the entire query string from the http request objext and tokenize it yourself (which would be bad and completely custom made for the search url only)